# iOS 8 CoreData Issue: recordChangeSnapshot:forObjectID:: global ID may not be temporary when recording

Tags: ios, core-data

I'm migrating my App from iOS 7 to iOS 8, and I've been receiving the following error in Xcode when I try to save the Core Data context. This error was not present in iOS 7 and Xcode 5.  it throws exception at below line

```
NSError * saveError = nil;
if(![self.managedObjectContext save:&saveError])
{ // crash on save context line.
   //error message.
}
```

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'recordChangeSnapshot:forObjectID:: global ID may not be temporary when recording.
I am sinking data on main thread and trying to save it in core data . 
Below is code for managed object context in app delegate class :

```
 - (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
        {
            if (_managedObjectContext != nil) {
                return _managedObjectContext;
            }

            NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
            if (coordinator != nil) {
                _managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
                [_managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
            }
            return _managedObjectContext;
        }

        // Returns the managed object model for the application.
        // If the model doesn't already exist, it is created from the application's model.
        - (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel
        {
            if (_managedObjectModel != nil) {
                return _managedObjectModel;
            }
            NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"MCRM" withExtension:@"momd"];
            _managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
            return _managedObjectModel;
        }

        // Returns the persistent store coordinator for the application.
        // If the coordinator doesn't already exist, it is created and the application's store added to it.

        - (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
        {
            if (_persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
                return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
            }

            NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"MCRM.sqlite"];

            NSError *error = nil;
            _persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
            if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error]) {

                NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
                abort();
            }

            return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
        }

        and it crash in data manager class :

        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {  
             NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
         }
```

Code work fine in iOS7 and Xcode5.1 . 
I have already tried with thread confinement (-[NSManagedObjectContext init]) to replace with [NSManagedObjectContext initWithConcurrencyType:] to NSConfinementConcurrencyType and NSMainQueueConcurrencyType with performBlockWithWait^{} code injection but still facing issue .

Comment: At any point are you using performBlockAndWait? And please in your question show how you are *creating* managed objects. If you are attempting to create them independent of a context, this is one of the many problems you may encounter.

Comment: nice to here you. I am creating it with moc using below code   NSManagedObject *newPickerObj = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:"EntityName" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext]; and the project I am working on is with legacy code. but when I run it on Xcode6.0 with iOS7 deployment target It is crashing.